# Is it possible to forward my Domain name to a free hosted website?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, pythonanywhere, domain-name, domain-forwarding

I have purchased a Domain name from BigRock. Is it possible to redirect this domain to my free hosted website on pythonanywhere.com with a sub-domain? for ex: myxyz.pythonanywhere.com

I am using a free plan of pythonanywhere.com which gives us a sub-domain with "pythonanywhere" as a parent domain.

Suppose, the Domain I've purchased is "myabc.com". I want to redirect all the requests on this URL (myabc.com) to my free hosted website (i.e. myxyz.pythonanywhere.com)

**Edit**: I tried the Domain Forwarding feature of BigRock. I entered "http://myxyz.pythonanywhere.com" in the redirection URL. In a couple of hours when I went to myabc.com, It was showing "myxyz.pythonanywhere.com refused to connect". which might be indicating that redirection was successful but Pythonanywhere is somehow blocking the redirection.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- that certainly should work, and we don't block stuff like this.  It's hard to work out what's going on without seeing it ourselves, so if you don't want to put your domain name on a public site like Stack Overflow, just drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible. BigRock should have a domain manager where you can add your pythonanywhere domain.

Comment: I tried the Domain Forwarding feature of BigRock (edited the description).